# Can't play MP3 File recorded using Microphone in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, microphone, recording

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Updates the XNA FrameworkDispatcher and checks to see if a sound is playing.
    /// If sound has stopped playing, it updates the UI.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    void dt_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try { FrameworkDispatcher.Update(); }
        catch { }

        if (true == soundIsPlaying)
        {
            if (soundInstance.State != SoundState.Playing)
            {
                // Audio has finished playing
                soundIsPlaying = false;

                // Update the UI to reflect that the 
                // sound has stopped playing
                SetButtonStates(true, true, false);
                UserHelp.Text = "press play\nor record";
                StatusImage.Source = blankImage;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The Microphone.BufferReady event handler.
    /// Gets the audio data from the microphone and stores it in a buffer,
    /// then writes that buffer to a stream for later playback.
    /// Any action in this event handler should be quick!
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    void microphone_BufferReady(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Retrieve audio data
        microphone.GetData(buffer);

        // Store the audio data in a stream
        stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        var isoStore = System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        if (isoStore.FileExists("AudioTest.mp3"))
            isoStore.DeleteFile("AudioTest.mp3");
        using (var targetFile = isoStore.CreateFile("AudioTest.mp3"))
        {
            // WavHeaderWriter.WriteHeader(targetFile, (int)stream.Length, 1, microphone.SampleRate);
            var dataBuffer = stream.GetBuffer();

            targetFile.Write(dataBuffer, 0, (int)stream.Length);
            targetFile.Flush();
            targetFile.Close();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the Click event for the record button.
    /// Sets up the microphone and data buffers to collect audio data,
    /// then starts the microphone. Also, updates the UI.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void recordButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get audio data in 1/2 second chunks
        microphone.BufferDuration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);

        // Allocate memory to hold the audio data
        buffer = new byte[microphone.GetSampleSizeInBytes(microphone.BufferDuration)];

        // Set the stream back to zero in case there is already something in it
        stream.SetLength(0);

        // Start recording
        microphone.Start();

        SetButtonStates(false, false, true);
        UserHelp.Text = "record";
        StatusImage.Source = microphoneImage;
    }
```

I have this code for recording using microphone and write it to a mp3 file in Local folder. While using emulator I can access the file and it plays using VLC player. But when I am using a Device I cannot open the file. Is there any solution

Comment: What's `stream`? I don't see anything mp3 related here, other than a filename. How are we meant to help?

Comment: Just putting .mp3 on the end of a file does not make it an mp3.  MP3 is specific way of encoding audio data.  You need to figure out what form the microphone data comes in, and then encode that into the format you want

Answer (score 0):

The audio data from the WP8 Microphone is not an MP3, it is in PCM wave format:

[Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21261195/microphone-sound-from-wp8-should-be-played-in-wpf-c-sharp-wave-header)

I suggest instead of looking to encode it as an MP3, you use WMA, another format directly supported by the built in API.  This question has the samples you need:

[Save Microphone Data to Audio File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25487256/compress-wav-file-to-wma-on-windows-phone-8)