# Windows Phone 8.1 audio format conversion

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, audio-converter

How can we convert audio in WP 8.1 from one format to another in a Memory Stream?

Ex. convert MP3 file to WAV (PCM).

I checked the following:

- NAudio is not yet supported on WP 8.1.
- The Media Foundation just supports a subset of APIs, and cannot be used for converting from one format to another.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try out the [MediaTranscoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.media.transcoding.mediatranscoder.aspx)  class for the conversion?

`Reference:` [Compress wav file to wma on Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25487256/)